# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: when trying to open a file

Tags: python, windows, file, operating-system

im trying to open a file, but whenever I open it it returns the error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:`. I have no idea why, I'll show you a bit of my code:

```
initialdir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
lockerdir = (str(initialdir) + str('/locker'))
try:
        file = open('openfile.ivd', 'r+')
        mostrecentpath = file.read()
        file.close()
    except:
        print("No files currently open")
        finishedprocess()

    filename = pathlib.Path(mostrecentpath).stem
    print(filename)
    fullfilename = os.path.basename(mostrecentpath)
os.chdir(lockerdir)
        print(filename)
        with open(fullfilename, "rb") as file:
            file_data = file.read()
            encrypted_data = fernet.encrypt(file_data)
            file.close()
        #writes to the binary of a file
        with open(fullfilename, "wb") as file:
            file.write(encrypted_data)
            file.close()
        os.chdir(initialdir)
```

openfile.ivd already exists. It contains the path of the last file taht was opened by my program. When printing filename I get the output, `test`, however in my full error I get the error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'test.txt\n'`. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, but this might help. Try using `strip` on all of the filenames (All the variables that are in the `open` function).

Comment: When you use `file.read()`, there is a newline character `\n` at the end of the line (almost always). You have to remove that using the string method `file.read().strip()`, as @AmirhosseinKiani says.

Comment: Thx I'll give it a try